# How can I parse two XML files from two URLs (Swift)

Tags: ios, xml, swift

I have two XML URLs. The first URL shows a `SongName` on the `Table` and the second URL has the `SongPath`. When I click the `SongName` on the table it goes to the `SongPath` in the second URL. This is the 
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRkq7.png). You can see the `SongName` URL in the code.

This the XML:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <SongName>AYA LIV LIVOKIM PEL?STANKTV</SongName>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <SongName>DîLAN PPP PELISTANK</SongName>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <SongName>KARIN BAL DAGRIM</SongName>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <SongName>RUKEN WERE CANE</SongName>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

This the second URL for the [SongPath](http://jo.sms2tv.com/PelistankApp/Defult_2.aspx) :

And this the XML :

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <SongPath>http://jo.sms2tv.com/PelistankApp/Songs/song1.mp3</SongPath>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <SongPath>http://jo.sms2tv.com/PelistankApp/Songs/song2.mp3</SongPath>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <SongPath>http://jo.sms2tv.com/PelistankApp/Songs/song3.mp3</SongPath>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <SongPath>http://jo.sms2tv.com/PelistankApp/Songs/song4.mp3</SongPath>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

And this my Swift code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, NSXMLParserDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{

    @IBOutlet var tbData : UITableView?

    var parser = NSXMLParser()
    var posts = NSMutableArray()
    var elements = NSMutableDictionary()
    var element = NSString()
    var title1 = NSMutableString()
    var date = NSMutableString()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.beginParsing()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func beginParsing()
    {

        posts = []
        parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL:(NSURL(string:"http://jo.sms2tv.com/PelistankApp/default.aspx"))!)!
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse()

        tbData?.reloadData()
    }


    //////////////////////////////////////XMLParser Methods

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String])
    {
        element = elementName
        if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("Table")
        {
            elements = NSMutableDictionary()
            elements = [:]
            title1 = NSMutableString()
            title1 = ""
            date = NSMutableString()
            date = ""
        }
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?)
    {
        if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("Table") {
            if !title1.isEqual(nil) {
                elements.setObject(title1, forKey: "title")
            }
            if !date.isEqual(nil) {
                elements.setObject(date, forKey: "date")
            }

            posts.addObject(elements)
        }
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String)
    {
        if element.isEqualToString("SongName") {
            title1.appendString(string)
        } else if element.isEqualToString("pubDate") {
            date.appendString(string)
        }
    }
  ///////////////////////////////////////////XMLParser Methods


    //////////////////////////////Tableview Methods
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")!

        if(cell.isEqual(NSNull)) {
            cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Cell", owner: self, options: nil) [0] as! UITableViewCell
        }

        cell.textLabel?.text = posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("title") as! NSString as String
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("date") as! NSString as String

        return cell as UITableViewCell
    }


  //////////////////////////////////////Tableview Methods


    /////// Table Action ( Cell clicked ) ///////

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        let row = indexPath.row
        print("Row: \(row)")

    }

    /////// Table Action ( Cell clicked ) ///////


    @IBAction func Song(sender: UIButton) {

        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewSong")
        self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)

    }

   @IBAction func BackTableToHome(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Home")
        self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }

    //////////Button SecandViewController ////
    @IBAction func SecondViewController(sender: AnyObject) {

        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewSong")
        self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }
}
```

Any advice please. I can make an MP3 player no problem, I just want it so that when I click on a cell in the table it will play the song in the same row in the second XML URL.

Comment: What's the error? You can't just post a large amount of code with no explanation. Provide details about what problem you are having.

Comment: @rmaddy i dont have error in my code i wand use two URL in my code and this URL's contains XML , the first one contain SongName and i parsing in the Table , and the second one contain the SongPath , i want when click in table cell play the song in the same row from the second URL , Example : i clicked in the row [0] for song name 123 , play song in the row[0] for the second xml (URL)  , you understand my case sir ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First parse your both API and store songs name and songs URL in an array. and access it whenever you want don't parse again and again.

> This answer is parsing using [SWXMLHash](https://github.com/drmohundro/SWXMLHash)

you can use [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) to make HTTP request

```
let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data!)
       for elem in xml["NewDataSet"]["Table"] {

            print(elem["SongName"].element?.text) //PRINT SONG NAME 
        }
```

For more about XML Parsing I have already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34269317/2803960)

//Here is what you wanted

```
    /////// Table Action ( Cell clicked ) ///////

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        let row = indexPath.row
        print("Row: \(row)")

        print(posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("date") as! NSString as String) //Prints the song url

    }
```

Here is the project link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2csGr9uKp1DN1VodkNndmtQR2c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: brother i already  print the song name but i need use the second URL example : when click in row [0] in the table PLAY the song in the row [0] from the second URL

Comment: @AhmadMahamid first parse and store songs name and songs URL in an array. and access it whenever you want don't parse again and again.